# Update the value in table row by id - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to increase the number value in a column called 'denda' every 24 hours followed by different starting date. For example if the date reach the current datetime so it start to count to 0.20 ..the next day should be 0.40. So the value should be different follow by starting date in a table.

this is my output

[contohgambar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd7NC.jpg)

and this is my code

```
$pulang = mysql_query("SELECT id_peminjam, t_pinjam, t_pulang FROM peminjaman WHERE status='LEWAT'");
$pulang2 = mysql_fetch_array($pulang);
$id = $pulang2['id_peminjam'];
$id2 = $pulang2['t_pinjam'];
$id3 = $pulang2['t_pulang'];

"</br>";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

$now = time(); 
$your_date = strtotime($id3);
$datediff = $now - $your_date;
$bil_lewat= floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

$jum_denda = ($bil_lewat * 0.20);

$format = number_format($jum_denda, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english :-D...by the way the number start to increase 0.20 every 24 hour by starting date Tarikh Perlu Hantar column.

Comment: Are you asking how to update the database with the new value?

Comment: thanks for asking :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use MySQL statement to solve your problem. Add "DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),t_pulang)*0.2" into your SQL statement to calculate the difference between the dates. As following, 
[MySQL 5.5 Date and Time Functions - datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), [MySQL NOW() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)

```
mysql_query("SELECT id_peminjam, t_pinjam, t_pulang, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),t_pulang)*0.2 FROM peminjaman WHERE status='LEWAT'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I user function on mysql found diff

example

> select DATEDIFF( now(),t_pulang) datediff , DATEDIFF( now(),t_pulang) *0.20 jum_denda from peminjaman where status='LEWAT'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guy for replying .. You guys already give me the idea to use DATEDIFF ...although ..the DATEDIFF code only read the Y-m-d date format..it can't read d-m-Y date format..so it is trouble me at first..until my friend decide to change the code like the code below.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT isbn,id_peminjam,nama,judul,t_pinjam,t_hantar,t_pulang,status, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),t_pulang)*0.2 As Differ FROM peminjaman WHERE status='LEWAT' LIMIT $posisi, $limit");
$no = $posisi + 1;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $format = $data['Differ'];
         $denda = number_format($format, 2, '.', '');
    echo "
        <tr>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$no</div></td>
          <td align='left'><div class='style4'>$data[nama]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$data[judul]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$data[t_pinjam]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$data[t_pulang]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$data[t_hantar]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;$data[status]</div></td>
          <td align='center'><div class='style4'>&nbsp;RM $denda</div></td>
          <td align='center'>
```